# Convert nested loop to list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a list of tuples to a list of strings by joining the tuple elements to a string. The problem is that some tuple values are not strings, so I have to convert them. I have successfully solved this problem with a nested loop. However, I can't seem to be able to come up with an equivalent list comprehension.

Here's my solution. I start with these values:

```
values = [(1, '2', 'X'), (2, '4', 'Y'), (7, '5', 'Z')]
```

The result should look like this:

```
result = ['1_2_X', '2_4_Y', '7_5_Z']
```

And here's my solution using nested loops:

```
values = [(1, '2', 'X'), (2, '4', 'Y'), (7, '5', 'Z')]
result = []
for v in values:
   new_v = []
   for s in v:
       new_v.append(str(s))
   result.append("_".join(new_v))
```

Is there an equivalent list comprehension or is this not possible? I kind of suspect that it is not possible because I append to `result` not in the inner loop, but in the outer loop, but I might be wrong.

As a bonus, maybe I'm overthinking this and there is a much simpler solution for what I want to achieve.

Comment: `output = ['_'.join(map(str, x)) for x in values]`

Comment: output = ["_".join([str(x) for x in i]) for i in values]

Comment: Wow, thanks for all these quick and great answers! Now since all answers are correct, which one should I accept?

Comment: @cbrnr You accept the one you are going to use. And if you in the future use another you should change to that (theoretically). That's my idea.

Comment: Well, the two answers other than yours are identical, and so are the two comments to the question... Do I take the one who answered first, or the one who used a slightly more readable syntax?

Comment: @cbrnr If they are answered within 1 or maybe 2 minutes (depening on length of answer): The one with best syntax. If 5 or more minutes separate them it is just a copy. Again, my idea.

Comment: I've suggested an edit to blue_note 's answer that makes it fit your scenario exactly, accept that one because it is more readable as an answer

Comment: Ignore the edit bit, I hadn't realised answer edits go through the review queue instead of just past the answerer, accept blue_note 's

Comment: Thanks @strava, I also thought that her/his answer is very slightly more readable, but you were faster. Both of you should get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = ['_'.join(str(token) for token in value) for value in values]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
['_'.join((str(s) for s in seq)) for seq in values]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take:

```
result = ['{}_{}_{}'.format(*i) for i in values]
```

Comment: similar to other solutions but less generic

Comment: @Shiva no it works, but assumes that there are always 3 items per tuple

Comment: @Shiva ofc it will :). I like options. I think it is very readable depending on what you do.

Comment: This didn't work for me, because it produced `['1___2', '2___4', '7___5']`. However, this modification makes it work: `['{}_{}_{}'.format(*i.split("_")) for i in values]`.

Comment: My bad, I just tested it out. Thanks @AntonvBR

Comment: @cbrnr hmm... dunno, did you use your right dataset?

Comment: Oops, sorry, had the wrong `values`. This does indeed work - nice!

Comment: @cbrnr sure! but ... tbh I would probably write it like others have suggested: `['_'.join([str(i) for i in x]) for x in values]`. But this could make sense if you are certain there are 3.